# Memoir ruled section, no indent after a section title ( \setbeforesecskip vs \setaftersecskip)

Tags: sectioning, memoir, indentation

I'm trying to have no indentation in first line after section title. Changing the argument of `\setbeforesecskip` and `\setaftersecskip`to positive and negative value  seem not to help (just "1sp" in`\setaftersecskip` gets some results but section title looks different then).

I noticed it's a tricky topic in memoir.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside, openright,twocolumn]{memoir} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Section rules
\newcommand{\SecRule}[1][\medskipamount]{\par                       
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+#1}
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{0.4mm}\par                             
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\parskip-.5\baselineskip+#1}}

\setbeforesecskip{-12mm}
\setaftersecskip {-1sp} 
\setsecnumformat{\csname  the#1\endcsname\par\nobreak\vspace{-0.1cm} 
\SecRule \par\nobreak } 

\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{
\fontsize{13pt}{12pt} \bfseries \centering \MakeUppercase{#1} \par 
\vspace{0.2cm} 
}
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Following the replies to these topics did not help
[First paragraph of section becomes indented after setting \setbeforesecskip (memoir class)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15856/first-paragraph-of-section-becomes-indented-after-setting-setbeforesecskip-mem?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[First paragraph indented after section title in margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232629/first-paragraph-indented-after-section-title-in-margin)

Comment: Thanks @cfr but it's the opposite: text should not be indented after a section heading, the first line should start where the other start with no extra space.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Misread your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a negative horizontal space[image: ![enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5N7O.png)

```
\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{
\fontsize{13pt}{12pt} \bfseries \centering \MakeUppercase{#1} \par
\vspace{0.2cm} 
\hspace{-0.15cm} 
\noindent
}
```